What would an army with futuristic technology do to create strong defensive points
This is set about 10,000 years in the future. Armor and shielding technology have gotten so good that projectile and explosion based attacks are virtually useless. The only effective weapons are particularly powerful nukes (rare) and particle based weaponry, i.e. lasers. This makes artillery and air power much less effective, as it's much more expensive than just using guns and the effect is similar. They have their uses, like as shock and awe tactics or extremely concentrated offensives, but they're not nearly as effective as they are today. In almost all situations, guns are the way to go, because they're cheaper and more efficient and the advantages of artillery and air are greatly reduced. This future society has captured but not perfected interstellar travel. Crossing the galaxy takes roughly 5 years, so the main way of logistics is to either waste a ton of money on millions of long range ships(reserved for the richest who want to show off), or send occasional massive stockpiles all at once in heavily shielded, cloaked ships. This is the traditional method, and these logistics ships are extremely difficult to intercept to the point that most don't bother trying.
An army of about 13 million(in control of about 1/4 of the planet already) with was dropped onto a planet and told to defeat a bunch of corporations who were causing trouble there. They make massive gains initially, but the corporations band together and start pushing them back. Their only source of supply is their big but finite stockpile that they brought with them, for reasons stated above. They had miscalculated their stockpile needs and resistance was stronger than expected, so after a few months, they're losing the war, down to less than 9 million front line soldiers. Their general decides to withdraw their main line to a more easily holdable position, behind a river to the south, a very drnse marshland in the center, and mountains in the north, to await the arrival of their second stockpile.
Their main problem is in the junction points between the three obstacles: they are a few miles across, essentially flat plains and provide opportunities for breakthroughs by enemy forces. These positions have to be defended as thoroughly as possible to avoid enemy forces getting into the open plains to their rear.
This army has access to energy shields, but they have a limited amount of them due to using most of them that were im their stockpile. They can withstand significant force, but once they're broken, they're dead forever. So they must use their available energy shields very sparingly. They are running out of their given stockpile of ammunition, so they must conserve it as much as possible until their requested supply delivery arrives in 3 months. They are almost out of artillery ammunition and are low on fuel, but they have enough to conduct one small armored offensive if they absolutely have to. They're using a bit of the planets infrastructure to produce a small amount of fuel and ammunition just in case they need it before their second stockpile arrives.
Given these factors, how would this army go about defending these open positions at the junction points between the three easily defendable positions?

This civilization with futuristic technology seems to be stuck in the 19th century, because apparently neither side in this technologically dichotomous war has any workable aircraft. In real history, fixed fortifications became completely obsolete at some point in the 1930s.

@AlexP sorry for the important detail i left out. Most of the aircraft are gone from the intense fighting, the planet has a total lack of a vital resource for modern aircraft, and neither side can import it due to logistical conditions and their location im the galaxy. The quickest delivery would take at least a year, assuming they can secure a supplier

They cannot repair or refurbish damaged aircraft, but they can sustain a population in the hundreds of millions? And against an enemy who has no aircraft, you don't need very modern aircraft to gain air supremacy... (The armies are in the range of 10,000,000 men. The army cannot be more than 5%, maybe in a dire emergency 10%, of the population, or else the economy crashes hard and everybody dies of starvation.)

@AlexP Normally, all that is left of aircraft after losing dogfights or getting hit by anti air in this universe is a pile of useless slag. Neither side is native to the planet, they are there for monetary or law enforcement purposes and don't care about the people. The native population of the planet is about 60 million. Also, anti air weaponry is one of the few things that the army isn't actively running completely out of, so any remaining air power of the other side would be promptly shot down

9 million is close to what the Axis and Soviets had, combined, during Operation Barbarossa, an offensive across ~3,000 kilometers of front line... before full mechanization and long-range missiles and the other things that make modern armies even more spread out than they were in WW2. Either this number isn't relevant to the specific small-scale tactical situation of holding a small open field, or your future army tactics are so radically unlike our own that we can only guess at what they might be able to do. In either case, we'd need far more details on the technology and doctrine.

1/2. I think it needs some work. Your attacks would go about it one of two ways. 1st secure an area then setup a space port. Once your supply line is figured out, you can move to the offensive. Basically how any army works. But you don't want that. Other strategy is that your force was always meant to forage and sustain itself. In which case your number is absurdly high. a Force of 13/9 million is INSANE. China with 1.4 billions have an active army of 2 million. Supply and commanding that much is a nightmare. It's not realistic. And fighting an entire planet opens you up to simple tactics

2/2. If you just put them all in one place. All your enemy got to do is starve you, while bombing the hell out of your army. It's as simple as that. Your army can't be expected to fight an entire planet like that. Either use good sound tactics, or something creative. I suggest you change the idea. Have them be sort of more independent fighting force. They work in smaller numbers, nothing on your scale. Can sustain themselves and don't just group up in large numbers. A force of 10000 having to defend themselves behind an enemy line is plausible A force of a 100 is actually a better story.

@Seallussus a few things. 1, as already mentioned, both sides have lost nearly of their planes and can't effectively replace them, so bombing isn't possible. My mention of bombings in the question is an error from me looking at an older draft, lol. Second, all 9 million aren't in one place, they're spread out over 3 fronts. The main front im talking about is about 4 million, pretty close to the eastern front if ww2 in a few ways, but that wasn't that relevant for the question. The planet had enough industry to sustain them had the enemy not destroyed most of it when retreating.

@Gregory You can in fact launch missiles from the ground. You also seem to forget artillery exists. Which goes all the way back to the 15 century, even before. Just read on the Napoleonic wars.
Ironic to bring up WWII. Weaker economic base, manufacturing, supply lines issues...etc were some of the reasons why it was simply impossible for the Axis to win. Meanwhile the USSR had a steady supply of stuff. More robust industrial base...etc. I'm sorry. Your situation is unrealistic. ANY military commander with half a brain, and a full planet, will crush your invaders.

Rely on local infrastructure for supplies with a modern army!? That is a recipe for a suicide mission. Militaries stopped relying on local resources  post industrialization because of all the problems this causes, such as infrastructure being the main target of weapons. The premise should have been flagged in planning that  if were attempted it would lead to complete disaster.

@Seallussus Artillery and missiles are not nearly as effective here as it is today. Projectile and explosion based attacks here are about as effective as trying to derail a freight train with a nerf gun. Artillery with the necessary power to be effective does exist, but it's so expensive that the enemy doesn't have very much of it, let alone enough to completely destroy the others position with it. And the enemy doesn't start with the full planet, the army started with a significant chunk from territory that was already theirs. You had no way of knowing that, so sorry for the confusion.

The Best Defense is a Strong Offense
This is an old maxim, but there is much truth in it. If you sit and wait for the enemy to come to you, eventually - you will loose. It is near impossible to 'win' a defensive war.
The best you can hope for is that the enemy loose their will to fight.
However - there are two things that jump out at me:
1: Your enemy is a Corporation. Corporations care about Control and Profits
2: You mentioned 'Impassable terrain'
To quote Ryan McBeth: Create Dilemas, not Problems
If your force sits and does nothing - then the enemy gets to mashall their forces, decide on the when/where/how of the attack.
You do not want this. You want to send small teams - and cross the 'impassable marshes' (So many instances in history of a Flank being left unguarded because one side believed it to be impassable and the other figured out a way).
These teams have one goal in mind - Sabotage and raise hell. This will force them to pull units away from the frontline to increase security, it will make their regular forces anxious and from a profit point of view, it will increase the cost of waging the war
You want to keep them distracted, chasing their tails, chasing phantoms, worried about what you are going to do, so that they can't concentrate on what they are going to do.

Thanks. A small correction. The army is just tring to hold a good position for 3 months until their second stockpile arrives, not indefinitely trying to "win" a defensive war. They plan to go on the offensive again after they receive reinforcements and supplies.

3 months of enduring wave after wave of attacks or 3 months of rear-echelon attacks, confusing the enemy for 3 months - which sounds more likely to succeed?
